# Fill Select tool

Tags: mesh, geometry, select

Any idea how i can select inner polygons on this screenshot?[image]

I'v seen a video where a guy used "Fill Select" and i wannna know if its an addon or not.
link on the vid with the timing:
https://youtu.be/p2VQ81jGWv4?si=ceFsLO0kxBW01YB-&t=665

Comment: I don't think it's possible by default so he probably uses an addon

Comment: Thank you, it might be the Smart Select addon. But i think this dud wrote the "Fill Select" script himself

Comment: Here someone has written a script, maybe it will work? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180113/how-can-i-select-all-inner-faces-of-a-current-selection-of-faces

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!